# run command after application was compiled

Tags: windows, visual-studio-2013, msbuild, build-process, post-build-event

I'm looking for a way to have an encrypted version of the `app.config` file in the ouput folder. Below I'll describe what I've done so far for accomplish this.

put those commands in the post-build event:

```
copy "$(ProjectDir)App.config" "$(ProjectDir)App_copy.config"
rename "$(ProjectDir)App.config" web.config
aspnet_regiis -pef connectionStrings "$(ProjectDir.TrimEnd('\\'))" -prov DataProtectionConfigurationProvider
rename "$(ProjectDir)web.config" App.config
```

This encrypt the file app.config properly. But it make the `app.config` no longer human redable. I'd like somehow to after the application compile and the app.config from `$(ProjectDir)` is in the output folder, run this command (to have the `app.config` file human readable again):

```
rename "$(ProjectDir)App_copy.config" app.config
```

How can I do that using VS build system?

Comment: An alternative would be to use NTFS' per-file encryption.

Comment: Your title says "after application run", your question says "after application compile"; which do you mean?

Comment: @IInspectable: I'll check out this, but will not the final result be same as in my question, i.e, end up without a human readable app.config?

Comment: @stijn: after compile. Edited title